# Converting from dictionary to Dask HighLevelGraph

Tags: python, dask

Dask's [HighLevelGraph](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/high-level-graphs.html) has a method to convert it to a Python `dict`, however, it is not clear how to build the `HighLevelGraph` from a `dict` (doing the reverse process). Alternatively, is there a way to get the dependencies (as in `HighLevelGraph.dependencies`) from a `dict` representing the graph ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question, you can use the `HighLevelGraph.from_collections` method from `HighLevelGraph` to create a new `HighLevelGraph` from a `dict`, as shown below:

```
dsk = HighLevelGraph.from_collections(<name>, <any dict>)
```